# wrong copying into struct

Tags: c, string

I am passing string into struct , i am doin it like this inside for loop

```
printf("copy = %s\n",copy_p);
str[i].string=(char*)malloc(strlen(copy_p)+1 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(str[i].string,copy_p);
printf("skop = %s\n" , str[i].string);
```

So if `copy_p` variable is "Program has stopped working" this is what happens

```
printf("copy = %s\n",copy_p); // copy = Program has stopped working
printf("skop = %s\n" , str[i].string); // skop = Program has stopped working
```

But if i call this `printf("%s\n",str[0].string)` it outputs `Program has stopped work!`  why is that? but it isnt like this all the time it works for the most of the inputs

Comment: What type is 'copy_p' and what it it's size?

Comment: If `copy_p` is a pointer, retrieve the string length with `strlen`.

Comment: I suggest you use a temporary: 'int tempSize=(sizeof(copy_p)+1;', then break on the line after and inspect tempSize.

Comment: In fact, I strongly suggest that you use temp locals every time you need to calculate some value for a library call argument.

Comment: Based on how you have placed the spaces, I don't think `strlen(copy_p)+1 * sizeof(char)` does what you think it does. (Not that it matters in this case, though, since `sizeof(char)` is, by definition, 1.)

Comment: There's no errors in the code you have posted. The problem must be elsewhere. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is incorrect regardless of the type of `copy_p`:

```
str[i].string=(char*)malloc(sizeof(copy_p)+1 * sizeof(char));
```

- If `copy_p` is an array of characters initialized with a string literal, i.e.

  ```
  char copy_p[] = "Program has stopped working";
  ```

  then `+1` is unnecessary, because array size already includes null terminator.
- If `copy_p` is a pointer `char *copy_p`, then you need to call `strlen` instead of `sizeof`, i.e.

  ```
  str[i].string=malloc(strlen(copy_p)+1 * sizeof(char));
  ```

**Note:** casting results of `malloc` is unnecessary in C.

Comment: Yes - I was trying to drop hints:)

Comment: tried with strlen and it did the same thing , this does not happen for all strings tho , most of them are fine after printing...

Comment: @user3706129 It looks like something else in your code is inserting a null terminator into your string some four characters before the end. The original code (with `sizeof` instead of `strlen`) this could have happened because an adjacent block got allocated to some other string or structure. With the `strlen` this could happen because of a memory error somewhere else. Try running the program through valgrind or some other memory profile to see what is going on.